# Empty Date Field

Tags: templating, datetime

I currently have an empty date field, it's unset in the field. I know from reading this becomes "Today's Date" but for some reason the following code is just not working when testing for `empty`? Unsure why this is?

```
{% if entry.eventStartDate is not empty %}

  {% elseif entry.eventStartDate > now %}
    There is a date and it's greater than now.

  {% elseif entry.eventStartDate < now %}
    There is a date and it's before now.

  {% else %}
    There is no date set.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What's the output of {{ dump(entry.eventStartDate) }}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty date field will return `null`. Your conditional is slightly off as you have an `elseif` straight after your first `if`. Try:

```twig
{% if entry.eventStartDate is empty %}
    There is no date set.
{% elseif entry.eventStartDate > now %}
    There is a date and it's greater than now.
{% elseif entry.eventStartDate < now %}
    There is a date and it's before now.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Absolutely bang on.